# passing value from redux store from Parent component to many children

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a `Parent` component which has 5 different children. All of the children use the same value from the redux store using the `useSelector` hook:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const { isLight } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.theme);

  return (
    <>
      <ChildA isLight={isLight} />
      <ChildB isLight={isLight} />
      <ChildC isLight={isLight} />
      <ChildD isLight={isLight} />
      <ChildE isLight={isLight} />
    </>
  )
}
```

In term of best practice and performance is it better to drill the `isLight` prop to each child or use `useSelector` in each child separately?

Answer (score 2):

when you call `useSelector` in each child component separately, then when `isLight` is updated, each child will be rendered.
in the example above, when `isLight` is updated, the parent component will be rendered, then each child will be rendered, so the only difference is the rerender of the parent component, it's basically the same thing, you can leave it like that unless you want avoid rerendering the parent component.

Comment: understood , in terms of rendering its better to call the use selector in each child component. (i save the parent rendering. also i avoid props drilling)
but in terms of efficiency is that matter?

Comment: @bennyhassan No, I think it is the same